# Loading an Image with AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to add a photo to a POST using the AFNetworking 2.0.
This ios App sends a post an a photo to a blog.
I can'f figure out why the images don't load.

Here is what I got so far:

```
// publish text and image
-(void)publishTextAndImage:(NSString*)resultDisplay and:(NSString*)subject with:(NSString*)nonce
{
imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 0.7); // create a data object from selected image

NSString *myUUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]; // create a UUID
NSString *formatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"/wp-content/uploads/%@\"/>",myUUID];
NSString *contentString = [formatString stringByAppendingString:resultDisplay];
NSString *moodString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.moodNumber];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"title":subject,
                             @"content":contentString,
                             @"status":@"publish",
                             @"author":@"wordpress",
                             @"user_password":@"xrayyankee",
                             @"nonce":nonce,
                             @"categories":moodString,
                             @"attachment":@"image/jpeg"};

 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:@"http://thrills.it/?json=posts/create_post" 
 parameters:parameters 
 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
 {
     if (selectedImage)
     {
         [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"photo" fileName:myUUID mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
     }

 } 
 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

 }
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

}

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Did you receive an error?

Comment: I have same problem with my project..
You don't need to change your simple code of posting of image..
but you need to change the code of webservice to post the image to specific wordpress post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, the code was fine it was an issue with the naming of the parameters, here it is:

```
// publish text and image
-(void)publishTextAndImage:(NSString*)resultDisplay and:(NSString*)subject with:    (NSString*)nonce
{
imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 0.7); // create a data object from     selected image

NSString *myUUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]; // create a UUID
NSString *formatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"/wp-    content/uploads/%@\"/>",myUUID];
NSString *contentString = [formatString stringByAppendingString:resultDisplay];
NSString *moodString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.moodNumber];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"title":subject,
                         @"content":contentString,
                         @"status":@"publish",
                         @"author":@"wordpress",
                         @"user_password":@"xrayyankee",
                         @"nonce":nonce,
                         @"categories":moodString};

 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:@"http://thrills.it/?json=posts/create_post" 
 parameters:parameters 
 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
 {
 if (selectedImage)
 {
     [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"attachment" fileName:myUUID     mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
 }

} 
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
 NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

so basically I removed the "attachment" parameter from the parameters dictionary and changed the name of the appended imageData to @"attachment". it was an issue of wordpress json api being very picky (:

Answer (score 4):

I use the AFNetworking in this way :

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://thrills.it/?json=posts"]];
NSURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"create_post" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
{
     if (selectedImage)
     {
         [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"photo" fileName:myUUID mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
     }

} ];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation    JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) 
{
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    float progressValue = (float)((double)totalBytesWritten/(double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    NSLog(@"%f", progressValue);
}];

[self.queue addOperation:operation];
```

.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *queue;
```

My client is created earlier but it's created like that.

I hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas. AFHTTPClient does not exist anymore in AFNetworking 2.0. I would have downgraded to 1.0 and give it a try but we just managed to solve the problem. It was a stupid issue of naming the parameters differently. thanks anyway and a vote up for you.