# Converting std string to nsstring

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv

I am developing an ios application by using opencv. Currently, after I get image from camera, I want to send this image to backend server. So I convert image from Mat format to NSString.

As you can see below:

```
    //Convert image from mat format to vector unchar
    cv::vector<uchar> buff;//buffer for coding
    cv::vector<int> param = cv::vector<int>(2);
    param[0]=CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
    param[1]=95;//default(95) 0-100
    cv::imencode(".jpg",image,buff,param);

    //Convert from vector unchar to string
    std::string imageString(buff.begin(), buff.end());
    NSLog(@"%lu",imageString.size());

    //Convert from string to NSString
    imageData = [NSString stringWithCString:imageString.c_str() encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"%@",imageData);
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)imageData.length);
```

Firstly, I convert image from mat to a unchar vector. Then convert this vector to a std string called imageString. Finally, convert this std string to NSString imageData.

However, the size of imageString is 80804 which I think should be correct. But the size of imageData is 4. I don't know what happens here.

- 2014-08-27 15:09:04.094 FaceDetection[14540:60b] 80804
- 2014-08-27 15:09:04.095 FaceDetection[14540:60b] ˇÿˇ‡
- 2014-08-27 15:09:04.097 FaceDetection[14540:60b] 4
- 2014-08-27 15:09:05.438 FaceDetection[14540:60b]

Here is the code:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imageData, @"imageData", latitude, @"latitude", longitude, @"longitude", nil];
```

And response from server:

2014-08-27 15:09:05.438 FaceDetection[14540:60b] ËÃ¿Ëâ¡53.28588327-6.21796840

Best regards

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know why size get decreased dramatically after converting from std string to nsstring

Comment: If you want to send it to server then Base64 is most preferable.

Comment: You shouldn't use JSON to send data to the server. 
Here's a tip:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789169/loading-an-image-with-afnetworking-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using NSSting as it will discard unprintable characters. Use NSData to send image info to your server.

Comment: I tried to use NSData. It works, but the problem is I want send them to server and I want to convert it to JSON. As you can see:NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imageData, @"imageData", latitude, @"latitude", longitude, @"longitude", nil];
    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:kNilOptions error:nil]; I am not sure if I can convert NSData to JSON like NSDictionary with a key

Comment: As was mentioned in one of the comments you can send image data in Base64 as it will convert it to printable character string, but it's not the best solution. Just don't use JSON for binary data - it was not intended for it. I suggest to send image data in multipart request.